# Problem installing qutip on Mac Catalina 10.15.6: "could not build wheels for qutip which use PEP 517"

Tags: python, macos, qutip

I am trying to install `qutip` on a Mac (Catalina 10.15.6). I am using:

- Python 3.8.3
- Anaconda 4.8.4

I create a virtual environment with the command `conda create -n qutip python=3.8 anaconda`. Here's the error message:

```
g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -

L/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/qutip/lib -arch x86_64 -L/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/qutip/lib -arch x86_64 /usr/local/opt/readline/include -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/qutip/cy/spmatfuncs.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/qutip/cy/src/zspmv.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/qutip/cy/spmatfuncs.cpython-37m-darwin.so -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
  ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/readline/include' for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qutip
Failed to build qutip
ERROR: Could not build wheels for qutip which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I looked around and I don't see anything recent for this. I tried to install qutip from source and I got the same error. Does anyone have any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Same issue here, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hello @FriendlyLagrangian (that's a great username), I didn't. I ended up buying a Mac M1 Pro, and it doesn't have that problem. I have never found a solution to it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I end up solving it but I really dont know what did the trick... Enjoy your new Mac!